# Stanford NLP Text Classifier, Custom Features and Confusion Matrix

Tags: stanford-nlp, text-classification

I using Stanford NLP Text Classifier (ColumnDataClassifier) from my Java code. I have two main questions.

1-) How do I print more detailed evaluation information such as a confusion matrix.

2-) My code already, does the pre-processing and extracts numeric features (vectors) for terms, such as binary features or TF-IDF values. How can I use those features to train and test the classifier.

Comment: This is a good resource to look at for the classifier: http://nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier

Comment: I don't think there is any immediate way to print out the confusion matrix.  Here is the javadoc for the class as well: http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.html

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp Thanks. Could you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685303/stanford-nlp-columndataclassifier-how-to-serialize-model-with-only-top-features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I asked a related question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361348/stanford-classifier-cross-validation-averaged-or-aggregate-metrics). `ColumnDataClassifier` does not have an option to output the metrics in a confusion matrix. However, if you look at the code in at [ColumnDataClassifier.java](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.java) you can see where the TP, FP, TN, FN are output to the stdin. This place has the raw values that you need. It could be used for a method that aggregates these into a confusion matrix and outputs it after the run, but you would have to write this code yourself.
2. The [wiki](http://nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier) has an example of how to use numerical features with the `ColumnDataClassifier`. If you use numerical features, take a look at these options from the [API](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.html) that allow you do apply some transformations:

   ```
   realValued  boolean false   Treat this column as real-valued and do not perform any transforms on the feature value.    Value
   logTransform    boolean false   Treat this column as real-valued and use the log of the value as the feature value. Log
   logitTransform  boolean false   Treat this column as real-valued and use the logit of the value as the feature value.   Logit
   sqrtTransform   boolean false   Treat this column as real-valued and use the square root of the value as the feature value. Sqrt
   ```