# Stanford NLP ColumnDataClassifier: How to serialize model with only top features?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

When training a model there is an option called `limitFeatures`. When I set this feature, say `100` ColumnDataClassifier uses just the top 100 features. However it still serializes all the features to the `model.ser.gz`. When I deserialize this file in my Java code, my program uses approx. 500M memory. Is there a way to create smaller models with just selected features?

I am using the tool from CLI. But any solution with Java is very welcome as well.  Here are the relevant code from the prop file:

```
useClassFeature=false
1.useSplitWordNGrams=true
1.useSplitWords=true
1.useNGrams=false
1.usePrefixSuffixNGrams=false
1.splitWordsRegexp=\\s+
1.maxWordNGramLeng=5
1.minWordNGramLeng=2
1.binnedLengths=10,20,30,50,75,100,200,300,500
1.useLowercaseSplitWords=true
1.useAdaptL1=true
1.limitFeatures=500
1.l1reg=5.0
featureMinimumSupport=5
featureWeightThreshold=10
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you've tried?

Comment: @AlejandroC. I edited the question. I am using the tool with CLI for now.